# Jmeter CSV file data status

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

I am beginner in jmeter.
I have an excel sheet with 1000 URLs.I want to check if all URLs are available and working or not on live server.

I want to get 200 status for all urls and if url is not present to live then it will give 404 status.

Can someone share me laymen process how to do that with screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

Use following components:

- CSV Data Set Config to create the URL from your CSV file
  [image: CSV Data Set]
- [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) that will use the URL variable

[image: HTTP Request config]